# Extract field from Array from HIVE column

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table in hive with following value. How can I extract "term" from such value?

```
col1
[{"code":"HE:PHP0000391","onto":"tellic","syns":["efo:hp0000391"],"term":"Thickened helices"}]
```

I tried the below code, but it gives me below error.

```
with cte as (
  SELECT
    col1 
    FROM table
  )

select get_json_object(col1,'$.variable1') as variable1,
get_json_object(col1,'$.variable2') as variable2
from cte
```

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: line 9:7 Wrong arguments ''$.variable1'': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFJson with (array<struct<code:string,onto:string,syns:array<string>,term:string>>, string). Possible choices: _FUNC_(string, string)
```